# How to change the using of the pattern repository loaded using interfaces for initializing the model? Laravel, Laracom

Tags: laravel, oop, design-patterns, laravel-5.7

Good day.

A store was created based on https://github.com/Laracommerce/laracom on **Laravel**.

In the process, it was noticed that, along with pulling up the implementation for the interface with a call like:

*use App\Products\Repositories\Interfaces\ProductRepositoryInterface;*

the binding of which is declared in RepositoryServiceProvider (app \ Providers \ RepositoryServiceProvider.php),

**direct calls like** *use App\Shop\Products\Repositories\ProductRepository* **are used**;

(e.g. here *app/Shop/Orders/Repositories/OrderRepository.php*)

You can find several similar examples in the code, and most often a direct address is required to invoke 
*$repositoryWithModel = new Repository($modelObject).*

I did not find a definite way out of this situation, I ask the advice of those who came across an example of quality implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of your `ProductRepository` expects a `Product` as constructor parameter. A respository should not do that. Instead if a repository has to handle a product model, it should be passed as a parameter to a function.

For example this:

```
    /**
     * @param Brand $brand
     */
    public function saveBrand(Brand $brand)
    {
        $this->model->brand()->associate($brand);
    }
```

Can be rewritten to:

```
    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param Brand $brand
     */
    public function saveBrand(Product $product, Brand $brand)
    {
        $product->brand()->associate($brand);
    }
```

If you remove the `Product` parameter from the constructor, then you can use the repository without creating it using the `new` keyword every time:

```
class BrandController extends Controller {

   public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $repository) {
       $this->repository = $repository;
   }

   public function linkBrandToProduct(Request $request): void {
      $product = $this->repository->findProductById($request->productId);
      $brand = $this->repository->findBrandById($request->brandId);

      $this->repository->saveBrand($product, $brand);
   }
}
```